# Get certain values from XML feed with a colon in the node name

Tags: php, xml, xml-namespaces

I can't seem to find a way to properly get some values from the following XML feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:newznab="http://www.newznab.com/DTD/2010/feeds/attributes/" encoding="utf-8">
 <channel>
  <atom:link href="https://REMOVED.com/api" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <title>REMOVED</title>
  <description>API Details</description>
  <link>https://REMOVED.com/</link>
  <language>en-gb</language>
  <webMaster>hello@REMOVED.com</webMaster>
  <category>Stuff</category>
  <generator>Me</generator>
  <ttl>10</ttl>
  <docs>https://removed.com/apihelp/</docs>
  <image url="https://removed.com/themes/shared/img/logo.png" title="REMOVED" link="https://removed.com/" description="Visit REMOVED"/>
  <newznab:response offset="0" total="125000"/>
  <item>
   <title>Fair.Go.2017.09.18.HDTV.x264-FiHTV </title>
   <guid isPermaLink="true">https://REMOVED.com/details/427d2b6c5fb3a0f73bd43be4bb8cff955700fd4d</guid>
   <link>https://REMOVED.com/getnzb/427d2b6c5fb3a0f73bd43be4bb8cff955700fd4d.nzb&amp;i=1&amp;r=3bc4e94ef14337e4e2b490a3897c48f6</link>
   <comments>https://REMOVED.com/details/427d2b6c5fb3a0f73bd43be4bb8cff955700fd4d#comments</comments>
   <pubDate>Tue, 19 Sep 2017 10:18:21 +0200</pubDate>
   <category>TV &gt; SD</category>
   <description>Fair.Go.2017.09.18.HDTV.x264-FiHTV </description>
   <enclosure url="https://REMOVED.com/getnzb/427d2b6c5fb3a0f73bd43be4bb8cff955700fd4d.nzb&amp;i=1&amp;r=3bc4e94ef14337e4e2b490a3897c48f6" length="168013625" type="application/x-nzb"/>
   <newznab:attr name="category" value="5030"/>
   <newznab:attr name="size" value="168013625"/>
   <newznab:attr name="files" value="17"/>
   <newznab:attr name="poster" value="provide@4u.net (yeahsure)"/>
   <newznab:attr name="prematch" value="1"/>
   <newznab:attr name="info" value="https://REMOVED.com/api?t=info&amp;id=427d2b6c5fb3a0f73bd43be4bb8cff955700fd4d&amp;r=3bc4e94ef14337e4e2b490a3897c48f6"/>
   <newznab:attr name="grabs" value="0"/>
   <newznab:attr name="comments" value="0"/>
   <newznab:attr name="password" value="0"/>
   <newznab:attr name="usenetdate" value="Tue, 19 Sep 2017 10:07:47 +0200"/>
   <newznab:attr name="group" value="alt.binaries.teevee"/>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I need the value from  and the values for size and usenetdate from those  nodes and put them in an array. There's only 1  in here but in the real feed there are hundreds.

Can't be that hard in PHP right? Yet XMLWriter, DOM and SimpleXML all failed me. Or I failed them.

Any pointers?

Comment: Please share code which you have tried and your expected output.

Comment: The element names are in the format `prefix:localname` where the prefix (e.g `newznab`) represents an XML namespace (here `http://www.newznab.com/DTD/2010/feeds/attributes/`). To process this XML you need to understand how your chosen processing library deals with XML namespaces. Usually you will want to locate elements using the (namespace, local-name) pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes in when using namespaces, it's quite simple to deal with them in any XML system, here I've used SimpleXML.  I've also assuming it's Channel that is repeated.

To use namespaces, you need to register them with the XML system so that it knows how to associate them with the search, so here I use `newznab` as the prefix to `attr`.  But this is what you see in the XML document, so it makes it easier to read. The XPath uses `[@name='size']` to make it find the instance of `attr` which has this attribute/value combination - and then it returns the `value` attribute.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('NewFile.xml');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("newznab", "http://www.newznab.com/DTD/2010/feeds/attributes/");

foreach( $xml->channel as $channel ){
    echo "Channel title=".(string)$channel->title.PHP_EOL;
    echo "size=".(string)$channel->xpath("descendant::newznab:attr[@name='size']/@value")[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo "usenetdate=".(string)$channel->xpath("descendant::newznab:attr[@name='usenetdate']/@value")[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```